# Forbidden for url error from http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/

Tags: python, django, soap, zeep

I am getting this "Forbidden for url" error when using zeep. Does someone knows what the root cause is?
I have tried to use some options from the Client object of zeep but to no avail.
Or is it something wrong in my WSDL file?
The strange part is that this code used to work fine a few months ago, and suddenly started getting this error.

This is the trace back from the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/src/app/attpcdaq/daq/tasks.py", line 33, in eccserver_refresh_state_task
    ecc_server.refresh_state()
  File "/usr/src/app/attpcdaq/daq/models.py", line 428, in refresh_state
    client = self._get_soap_client()
  File "/usr/src/app/attpcdaq/daq/models.py", line 308, in _get_soap_client
    return EccClient(self.ecc_url)
  File "/usr/src/app/attpcdaq/daq/models.py", line 65, in __init__
    client = SoapClient(wsdl_url)  # Loads the service definition from ecc.wsdl
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zeep/client.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.wsdl = Document(wsdl, self.transport, settings=self.settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zeep/wsdl/wsdl.py", line 92, in __init__
    self.load(location)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zeep/wsdl/wsdl.py", line 97, in load
    root_definitions = Definition(self, document, self.location)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zeep/wsdl/wsdl.py", line 193, in __init__
    self._load(doc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zeep/wsdl/wsdl.py", line 198, in _load
    self.parse_types(doc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zeep/wsdl/wsdl.py", line 330, in parse_types
    self.types.add_documents(schema_nodes, self.location)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zeep/xsd/schema.py", line 111, in add_documents
    document = self.create_new_document(node, location)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zeep/xsd/schema.py", line 195, in create_new_document
    schema.load(self, node)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zeep/xsd/schema.py", line 421, in load
    visitor.visit_schema(node)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zeep/xsd/visitor.py", line 165, in visit_schema
    self.process(child, parent=node)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zeep/xsd/visitor.py", line 93, in process
    result = visit_func(self, node, parent)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zeep/xsd/visitor.py", line 238, in visit_import
    schema_node = self._retrieve_data(location, base_url=self.document._location)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zeep/xsd/visitor.py", line 1199, in _retrieve_data
    url, self.schema._transport, base_url, settings=self.schema.settings
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zeep/loader.py", line 87, in load_external
    content = transport.load(url)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zeep/transports.py", line 122, in load
    content = self._load_remote_data(url)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zeep/transports.py", line 135, in _load_remote_data
    response.raise_for_status()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 960, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/
```

Comment: Have you checked your firewall?

Comment: The firewall of the computer is off. Could this be due to a firewall on the network connection?

Comment: Related issue (no answer so far): https://github.com/mvantellingen/python-zeep/issues/1317

Comment: It looks like this happens to me when I make several calls in a row. The first ones work well and then at some point they all fail. Maybe it's a rate-limiting mechanism?

Answer (score 1):

You need to cache the WSDL by enabling transport caching:

```py
from zeep.cache import InMemoryCache

Client(soap_url, transport=Transport(
  cache=InMemoryCache(),
))
```

The [official documentation](https://docs.python-zeep.org/en/master/transport.html?highlight=cache#caching) recommends using the `SqliteCache` instead of the `InMemoryCache`:

```py
from zeep import Client
from zeep.cache import SqliteCache
from zeep.transports import Transport

transport = Transport(cache=SqliteCache())
client = Client(
    'http://www.webservicex.net/ConvertSpeed.asmx?WSDL',
    transport=transport)
```